# How to hide specific fields which are extracted via populate query

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

My schemas are as follows:

order.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var foodtruck = require('./foodtruck.js');
var payment = require('./payment.js');
var Items = require('./items.js');


var order = new Schema({
    order_status:Number,   //0 place 1 accepted 2 cooked 3 cancelled
    foodtruck_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'foodtruck'},
    customer_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'user'},
    items:[{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}],
    user_type:Boolean,
    order_time:Date,
    order_rating:{type:Number,default:5.0},
    order_issue_comments:String,
    order_special_instruction:String,
    order_total:Number,
    order_location:String,
    order_coupon_code:String,
    payment_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'payment'}
},{ versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('order',order);
```

foodtruck.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Items = require('./items.js');


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:{type:Number,default:5},
    foodtruck_total_votes:{type:Number,default:0},
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_open_status:{type:Number,default:1},   //0 open 1 closed
    foodtruck_starting_timing:String,
    foodtruck_closing_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:String,
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'items'}]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

items.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_stock:Number,   //0 available 1 last 5 items 2 not available
    item_quantity_ordered:{type:Number,default:0},
    item_discount_price:Number,
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    no_of_likes:{type:Number,default:0}
},{ versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('items',ItemSchema);
```

Now my query is as shown below:

```
var getOrderList = function(req, res) {
    var foodtruck_id = req.body.foodtruck_id;
    if ((foodtruck_id) && (foodtruck_id.trim() != '')) {
        order.find({
            'foodtruck_id': foodtruck_id.trim()
        }).populate('foodtruck_id').populate('customer_id').populate('items').exec(function(err, orderList) {
            if (err) res.json({
                status: '500',
                message: 'There was no order found'
            });
            else {
                res.json({
                    status: '200',
                    message: 'Order list',
                    data: orderList
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            status: '404',
            message: 'Please enter valid id'
        });
    }
};
```

The response is as show below:
[image: order response]

Now, what happens is when I put populate query for "foodtruck_id", it also shows item_list attached with it. Is there any way through which I can hide **item_list** field while populating **foodtruck_id** query?

Answer (score 2):

1.
You can use **'-'** to exclude a key after populate.

```
.populate({path:foodtruck_id,select:'-item_list')
```

2. If you want to select any specific key example you only want **foodtruck_name** .
   You can do this way

   .populate({path:foodtruck_id,select:'foodtruck_name')

to read more about populate you can visit [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Hey @Shumi, how can we exclude a field from array of objects?